# Sum of cosines in a transmitter

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Is there a closed form solution to this sum?
$$ \max \sum_{k=1, 2, ...}^n \cos (k+m(k) \pi /4), m(k)= 0, 1, 2, or 3$$
The application where this arises is calculating the peak voltage of a radio transmitter handling *n* carrier frequencies, each orthogonal to the others and digitally modulated in 4 phases http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QPSK#Quadrature_phase-shift_keying_.28QPSK.29
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OFDM

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use $k$ for the summation variable, because I'll need the complex number $i$.
Start with $$\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(ik) = \dfrac{\exp(i(n+1)) - \exp(i)}{\exp(i)-1}
 = A (e^{in} - 1)$$
where $A = e^i/(e^i - 1)$.  What you're asking for is the maximum of the real parts of $A e^{ij\pi/4} (e^{in}-1)$ for $j=0,1,2,3$.  The problem is that which $j$ gives the maximum 
depends on the phase of $e^{in}$, i.e. on the fractional part of $n/(2\pi)$, and knowing this in "closed form" as a function of $n$ implies a lot of control over
rational approximations of $1/(2\pi)$.